# Tizen emulator not detecting DNS settings

Tags: tizen, tizen-emulator

I have 32-bit windows 7 Enterprise edition with `Tizen sdk 2.2.1` installed. Problem is `Tizen emulator` is not detecting DNS settings. I can open website using ip address of website but not by typing name of website in browser of emulator.
What can be problem here. Why emulator is not detecting DNS settings.

Comment: What's in `/etc/resolv.conf` ?